# How to give external AWS IAM user access to specific S3 Bucket folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to give external users access to a single Amazon S3 bucket folder. I have their ARN information but I am having an issue granting access.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "S3AccessPolicy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "TestAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "<external ARN>"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::rootlevelbucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::rootlevelbucket/specificfolder/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is it a policy you put on bucket? If so, I guess it is missing the principal. But I believe the best approach is to create a role with trust to another account.

Comment: I have the principal, I just don't want to expose it in the post. The end user is a client of ours and would be too much to allow for a trust just to be able to download s3 objects..

Comment: What do you mean by "having an issue granting access"? Are you getting an error, or is the problem that they cannot access the objects? You could temporarily use `"Principal" : "*"` to see whether this fixes the problem and, therefore, whether the problem is with the policy or elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is 2 sides to cross account access.  You have the first part with the bucket policy, but the admin for the external account needs to grant the user access to the S3 with a IAM policy like below.  You can use the s3:* on the IAM policy because you bucket policy will restrict to just the commands you list.

[AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example2.html#access-policies-walkthrough-cross-account-permissions-acctB-tasks)

IAM Policy for external user:

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
      {
         "Sid": "RootlevelbucketAccess",
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": [
            "s3:*"
         ],
         "Resource": [
             "arn:aws:s3:::rootlevelbucket",
             "arn:aws:s3:::rootlevelbucket/specificfolder/*"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```